# Jquery submitting a form with a custom command

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible to submit a form with a custom command in Jquery:

Here is my script:

```
$(document).on('submit cmd+return (cant get to work or anything else...)', '.dbForm', function(e) {
     // sumbmit form...
});
```

Is it possible to do a .on('submit event.keyCode = 91 etc? ')...

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In order to not to use any plugin and with raw jQuery you can use it like this:

```js
$(document).bind('keypress', function(event) {
    if( event.metaKey && event.which == 13 ) {
        alert('bing! cmd+return');
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Then you can have a form submit function in your bind function.

In order  to have the keycodes or `which` you can take a look at these link:
https://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/javascript-keycodes/
https://unixpapa.com/js/key.html